# Specifying device specific functions in struct

Tags: c++, c, struct, embedded, typedef

I am working with firmware, trying to make a device-independent library.  The library uses I2C to communicate, a simple and common protocol for those who don't know what it is.  I2C uses two functions that I"m concerned with, read and write.  Using I2C on different microcontrollers and such is different for each core mainly and I'm looking for a way for the library to be passed the functions so it can use them in a consistent manner.

How can I make a struct that a user can set variables to functions.
Something like:

```
typedef struct I2C_setup{
    function read = device specific read function;
    function write = device specific write function;
}
```

and then I could call

```
I2C_setup I2C;
```

And thereafter

```
(return type) RegisterRead = I2C.read(register address);
```

Would I use function pointers or...what?

Comment: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html

Comment: You have rather answered your own question.  Function pointers is exactly what you have described.  That said since you tagged it C++, there are other possibilities that are C++ specific.  Everything you ever wanted to know about function pointers is exhaustively covered at http://www.newty.de/fpt/

Comment: Note that `register` is a reserved word in C and C++ - you cannot use it as a data type name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function pointer is a good idea.  You can defined your prototype as

```
typedef struct I2C_setup{
  (*I2C_Read_Func)(uint32_t devAddr, uint32_t subAddr, uint8_t *pData, size_t lenght);
}
```

your actual function as

```
I2C_Read(uint32_t devAddr, uint32_t subAddr, uint8_t *pData, size_t lenght);
```

and you can assign it by

```
I2C_setup I2C;
I2C.I2C_Read_Func = I2C_Read;
```